# React Native - Vector icons in Navigation bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-vector-icons

In my React Native app, I would like to use Vector Icons as navigation bar buttons.
For that, I'm using: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons
For navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/

I managed to set the icons as well, but when I tap the buttons, I get an unwanted effect where the background turns black.
Is there a way how I can keep the background color transparent also when the button's pressed?

Here's my code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state

    return {
    headerTitle: "Blog posts",
    headerRight: (            
        <Icon.Button name="quote-right" backgroundColor="transparent" color="black" onPress={() => params.postComment()}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}></Text>
        </Icon.Button>            
      ),
    headerLeft: (                                     
        <Icon.Button name="navicon" backgroundColor="transparent" color="black" onPress={() => params.postComment()}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}></Text>
        </Icon.Button>                                                                     
      ),
    };
};
```

And here's what I got:

[image]

Comment: What package are you using for the navigation?

Comment: react-navigation

Comment: Did you try this solution: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/429#issuecomment-281915822?

Comment: I did. I can style all elements in the bar, I just can't get rid of that unwanted effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prop you are looking for is [`underlayColor`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight#underlaycolor), that's the one you should set to `transparent`.

```
<Icon.Button
   name="quote-right"
   backgroundColor="transparent"
   underlayColor="transparent" // This one
   color="black"
   onPress={() => params.postComment()}
>
     <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}></Text>
</Icon.Button>
```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you Sir!